# Adjust height of LI depending on LI of different height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating inline LIs and would like their height to be similar. The problem here is that when one of my LI has a long text, this LI will have a bigger height and the others don't adjust. (I'm using bootstrap to create my rows)

http://jsfiddle.net/q5stk2yp/ (live example)

And HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-custom">
  <ul style="border:1px solid" class="row table-row">
    <li style="width:200px" class="table-cell">title 1</li>
    <li style="width:20%" class="table-cell">Name with very long description to create multiple lines and show what I would like to to.</li>
    <li class="table-cell">title 3</li>
    <li class="table-cell">title 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul style="border:1px solid" class="row table-row">
    <li class="table-cell">test 1</li>
    <li class="table-cell">test 2</li>
    <li class="table-cell">test 3</li>
    <li class="table-cell">test 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: One option could be text-overflow:eclipse

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes I know but this is not an option... I want to display the whole text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make elements match their tallest sibling's height by using `display: table-cell`.

This should work in IE8+ and all other browsers:

```css
.table-custom {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.table-row {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.table-custom > ul > li {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-custom">
  <ul style="border:1px solid" class="row table-row">
    <li style="width:200px" class="table-cell">title 1</li>
    <li style="width:20%" class="table-cell">Name with very long description to create multiple lines and show what I would like to to.</li>
    <li class="table-cell">title 3</li>
    <li class="table-cell">title 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul style="border:1px solid" class="row table-row">
    <li class="table-cell">test 1</li>
    <li class="table-cell">test 2</li>
    <li class="table-cell">test 3</li>
    <li class="table-cell">test 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is with jQuery.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oe4g2etw/6/

And here is the JS code you'll need:

```
// During the first load...
// Find the max height of the elements...
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".table-custom li").map(function (){
    return $(this).height();
}).get());

// And set all the list elements to that max height
$(".table-custom li").css('height', maxHeight);
```

If you want to also make it responsive you need to add a listener that checks for the window width change, then recalculates the height of the tallest element and sets it to all your list items:

```
// When the window is resized...
$( window ).resize(function() {
  // Remove the 'height' attribute...
  $(".table-custom li").css("height", "");

  // Find the max height of the elements...
  var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".table-custom    li").map(function (){
      return $(this).height();
  }).get());

  // And set it to all the elements
  $(".table-custom li").css('height', maxHeight);
});
```

Hope this helps!

PS: Don't forget to include jQuery in your `<head>` if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try it because the other answer seems easier (no jquery required...)

Comment: Thank you!  This was the only way I got it to work in my case.