# Make <a> tag to take 100% height of inline-block parent

Tags: html, css

I want to make `#menu a` tag take up 100% of the height of its parent element. The parent element forms part of a horizontal list, so has `display: inline-block` set.

However, the `a` tag does not extend the full height of parent div, despite me setting it to `display: block; height: 100%;`.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqec16we/12/

Would anyone know if this can be done?

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

#hi, #menu {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}

#hi {
  font-size: 28px;
}

#menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add line-height propert with a value, for example,

```
#menu a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height:40px;  /*MODIFICATION*/

}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: right;
  
}

#hi, #menu {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  
}

#hi {
  font-size: 28px;
  
}

#menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height:40px; /*MODIFICATION*/
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="hi">
HI
</div>

<div id="menu">
 <a href="#">Menu</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to find the ***magic*** value for that `line-height`.

Comment: Here is how you find that number using javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730663

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to do the equal height columns for either known or unknown height container, also good for centering both horizontally and vertically. Example:

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#hi {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#menu {
  display: flex;
}
#menu a {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 5px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="hi">HI</div>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't need the `<div>` around the `<a>`, it can be easier. Example:

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
}
#hi {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#menu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="hi">HI</div>
  <a id="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
</div>
```

You can also use CSS table for supporting older browsers. Example:

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#hi,
#menu {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#hi {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="hi">HI</div>
  <a id="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
</div>
```